# How to pass value from web.config to external js file?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I Have web.config file

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="interval" value="100"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Im trying to pass value "100" to js file in my folder Scripts to change interval of slide.
This is my js file

```
   $(function () {


    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow >div:first')
          .slideToggle(500)
          //.fadeOut(1000)
          .next()
          //.fadeIn(1000)
          .slideToggle(500)
          .end()
          .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, interval); <-- here

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the value serverside. You can do this in the controller and store it in the viewbag:

```
ViewBag.SlideShowInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SlideShowInterval"];
```

Then in your view, making sure it gets rendered *before* the `@Scripts.Render()` which renders the code you show, for example using the scripts section that comes with the default MVC layout:

```
@section scripts
{
    var slideShowInterval = '@ViewBag.SlideShowInterval';
}
```

Then change your script file to give the variable a more meaningful name:

```
setInterval(function () {
    // ...
}, slideShowInterval);
```

Comment: when i use this i get an error : SlideShowInterval is not defined

Comment: @None that's because it starts with a lower case `s`.

Comment: @None I can't debug your code from here. Good luck.

Comment: i I succeeded to figure it out ... with session and hidden field but i used r code also :)